# Find maximum number from array in assembly program

Tags: assembly, nasm, dosbox

I have written a program to find max number from array of 15 numbers but my output is coming wrong. I have store result in AX register.

Here is my code.

```
[org 0x0100]

array_nums: dw 19, 50, 30, 24, 19, 2, 5, 6, 40, 8, 23, 16, 17, 28, 86
max: dw 0
        mov bx, 0 ; initialize array index to zero
        mov ax, 0 ; initialize min to zero

        mov ax, [array_nums+bx]     ; max number to ax
        mov cx, 15

maxvalue:   cmp ax, [array_nums+bx]     ; find the maximun number
            jge maxloop                 ; if greater or equal number
            mov ax, [array_nums+bx]     ; ax contains the maximun number
maxloop:

        add bx, 2                   ; advance bx to next index
        loop maxvalue

        mov [max], ax               ; write back maximun in memory

        mov ax, 0x4c00              ; terminate program
        int 0x21
```

Comment: I don't see your program generating any output at all. What output do you get?

Comment: in AX Register i get 49 value and in BX 1E

Comment: Don't put your data at the start, or it will be executed as code. Move it to the end. Also, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: @Jester ok thanks for this info.

Comment: add a 'jmp start' right after the 'org 0x100' and a 'start:' label before the first line of your main program, to set the entry point. Also you may want to take a look at the 'lodsw' instruction ( http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/lodsw.htm )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'I have to store the result in ...' tells me this is probably a homework.

To please your teacher, don't just write a program able to solve the one task. Write a function (to make it reusable), use an API (either some standard, or define your own, like "pointer in array must be defined in BX". then embed this function into a program, to test it.

Something like this perhaps (shot from the hip, test it before you use it ;-) )

```
[org 0x0100]
jmp start

array_nums: dw 19, 50, 30, 24, 19, 2, 5, 6, 40, 8, 23, 16, 17, 28, 86

; ----------------------------------------------------------
; find the largest value in an array of ints
; in-params:
;   CX = number of values in array
;   BX = pointer to array
; out-params
;    AX = biggest value

findBiggest:
            mov ax, [bx]     ; first number to ax
            mov cx, 15

maxvalue:   cmp ax, [bx]     ; find the maximun number
            jge maxloop      ; if greater or equal number
            mov ax, [bx]     ; maximum number was larger
maxloop:
            add bx, 2        ; advance bx to next index
            loop maxvalue
            ret
; ----------------------------------------------------------

 start:     mov bx, offset array_nums     ; use find function on 'array_nums'
            mov cx, 15
            call findBiggest

            ; add some code here to show a
            ; message if AX is what you expected or not
            ; AX should be 86 for the example array    

            mov ax, 0x4c00              ; terminate program
            int 0x21
```